# Difference between $\sum_{n=1}^{k} f(n)+\sum_{n=1}^{k} g(n)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{k} [f(n)+g(n)] $

Tags: summation

What is difference between $$\sum_{n=1}^{k} f(n)+\sum_{n=1}^{k} g(n)$$ and
$$\sum_{n=1}^{k} [f(n)+g(n)] $$

Comment: Why would you expect any difference?

Comment: İs there no difference?

Comment: @Soru There is no difference whatsoever, since addition is commutative and associative.

Comment: No difference as long as the sum is finite.

Comment: Not even a shred of beginning of a difference.

Comment: Thank you everyone. İf $k$ to infinity?

Comment: Then we get silly things such as:
$$0=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-1)\ne\sum_{n=1}^\infty1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty1=\infty-\infty$$

Comment: If both are convergent series separately, then your statement holds

Comment: I understood..Thank you so much.

Comment: @Joel False.  If both are *absolutely convergent* then the statement holds.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt it holds from simple sum of limits theorems. Most of the time you need absolute convergence, but not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference.

Note that if the summation was up to infinity, then there actually would be difference since you cannot change the order of the summation if the sum does not absolute converges. But in your case the sum is finite, therefore it is just a summation between a finite number of elements, and there is no problem in splitting up the sum.

Answer (score 0):

If your $+$ operation is associative (which is the minimum required for operations to make any sense), then there is absolutely no difference.

Comment: You need commutativity as well